# how to use a while condition for a given task?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am fetching user details using date

```
if(date("d")==1) {
    $time  = "m";
}
if(date("l")=="Friday") {
    $time  = "w";
}
$time  = "d";

$sql=mysql_query("select user from table_users where $reprt=".$time .");
while($row=mysql_fetch_Array($sql) {
    $sql==mysql_query("select * from table_register where $user="$row[0]");
}
```

here when `(date("d")==1)` i want to select statement using both d and m how is that possible.

Comment: So you want to have two values for report_frequency when (date("d")==1) ???

Comment: I hope this is not the actual code from your PHP file, because it really has a lot of syntax errors

Comment: Downvoted, as this hasn't been copy-and-pasted from the code you actually tried - this won't run, as @Stardev says. Please take care when asking questions.

Comment: @riz - pleased you've got an answer, but it's much better to also thank the person that helped you, and to respond to other answers and comments appropriately. People have made an effort to assist you, so you should make an effort back `:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see if I got this right... you should should be doing this only in one query if I understand properly

select * from table_register where $user in (select user from table_users where $reprt=".$time)

would be a much better query then what you have set up... still not the best but at least it's only 1 query.

to the actual question, you should just change your code to the following

```
if(date("d")==1)
{
 $time  = "m";
}
if(date("l")=="Friday")
{
 $time  = "w";
}

if($time == "m") // this is when you want to also search for d right?
{
  //we do what I suggested earlier with a slight change
  mysql_query("select * from table_register where $user in (select user from table_users where  $reprt=".$time." OR $reprt=d)");
}
else
{
  //we do what I suggested earlier
  mysql_query("select * from table_register where $user in (select user from table_users where  $reprt=".$time.")");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have a String. name it S. you also have a string 
query = "select * from table_register where "

what you have to do is

```
 query = "select * from table_register where "  
  if(date("d")==1){
           s = "$report_frequency  = \"m\" OR $report_frequency  = \"d\" ";
    }
    elseif(date("l")=="Friday"){
         s = "$report_frequency  = \"m\" ";
    }
    else{
    s = "$report_frequency  = \"d\" ";
    }

    query = query.s;

    $sql=mysql_query(query);
    ...
```

In other word, construct your query string dynamically using Strings

Comment: Is this pseudocode? Variables in PHP need a dollar prefix, so as it stands, this response is rather misleading.

Comment: consider it  something like an algorithm. I just edited the code posted in the question. I should had spent a bit more time answering... sorry

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're using `$time  = "d";` outside the IFs, so you'll always have `$time=d`, so replace the code with this:

```
if(date("d")==1){
  $time  = "m or $reprt='d'";
}
if(date("l")=="Friday"){
  $time  = "w";
}

$sql=mysql_query("select user from table_users where $reprt=".$time);
while($row=mysql_fetch_Array($sql){
  $sql=mysql_query("select * from table_register where $user='$row[0]'");
}
```

Comment: You've copied three syntax errors from the OP - two missing semicolons and an incorrect usage of `==`.